# Javascript - Find Value of Item in Array by Knowing Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have a JavaScript array:

```
var myArray = [linkA, linkB, linkC, linkD, linkE, linkF, linkG, linkH, linkI, linkJ];
```

I know the value of the index from other calculations. So what I want to do is find an item in the array based on the known index value.  Here's what I've tried so far but it's not working:

```
var myIndex = 1; //Set from other calculations

var myIndexValue = myArray.find(myIndex);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Value Pair" in the title, but to get an item with an index, it's just `myArray[myIndex]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access it like so:

```
myArray[myIndex]
```